# Java authentication, authorization service (JAAS)

Tags: security, java, authentication

I am not getting resouces for the JAAS.

I dont know that is this appropriate place to ask this but help me.

Thanks

Comment: There is an enormous tutorial provided with the Javadoc. -1 for zero effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following two article to start with JAAS:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pj2ee9.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-sec2/index.html

These article has further resources to look into.